# How to create "autoincrement" trigger on update in sql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want simulate autoincrement on update on row counter.

My trigger is:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `db`.`token_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `token` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE `token` SET `counter` = `counter` + 1 WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
END
```

But I am getting a error:

## 1442 - Can't update table 'token' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: You need to expand on what you are trying to achieve here - my guess is delete the old record and add the new.

Answer (score 0):

Because your description is not detailed enough for a proper answer, maybe the following may help:

Option 1:
You can create a procedure, which selects the highest value, adds 1 and updates the last updated row.

Option 2:
If you don't use that table as a reference somewhere, make the AI-column the PK and use "REPLACE INTO..." instead of insert/update.